# JQuery плагин для поворота элемента

Tags: jquery, плагин

Ищу JQuery плагин, который может повернуть элемент на конкретное количество градусов. Также при запросе будет возвращать угол текущего поворота (плагин JQueryRotate так не может).

Comment: А чем вас CSS3 решение не подходит?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: есть такая функция в CSS3 rotate. Хорошо, давайте так: вам если решение будет просто на CSS (без JavaScript) подойдёт или нет?

Comment: плагин JQueryRotate использует transform: rotate(). Если не использовать его, то будет сложно получить угол текущего поворота

Comment: Хорошо, а если вы можете применить CSS `transform: rotate`, зачем вам jQuery-плагины?

Comment: Если не использовать их, то будет сложно получить угол текущего поворота

Comment: Почему сложно? Устанавливаете `$("selector").css("transform", "rotate(45deg)")`. Затем извлекаете `var transform = $("selector").css("transform")`. Затем либо `substr`, либо регулярным выражением.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Добавил ответ с рабочим примером.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для данной задачи можно обойтись и без jQuery-плагина.

Устанавливаем значения через jQuery: `$("selector").css("transform", "rotate(45deg)")`.

Затем извлекаете `var transform = $("selector").css("transform")`. Затем к переменной `transform` извлекаем значение из матрицы.

Пример:

```js
function setAngle(degrees) {
  $("img").css("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)");
}

function getAngle() {
  var transform = $("img").css("transform");
  var matches = transform.match(/matrix\((.*?)\)/i);
  if (matches == null) return null;
  var values = matches[1].split(', ');
  var a = values[0];
  var b = values[1];
  return Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
}

$(".rotation-getter-button").click(function() {
  alert(getAngle());
});

$(".rotation-setter-button").click(function() {
  setAngle($(this).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB7Si.jpg" />

<button class="rotation-setter-button">
  -30
</button>

<button class="rotation-setter-button">
  0
</button>

<button class="rotation-setter-button">
  45
</button>

<button class="rotation-setter-button">
  90
</button>

<button class="rotation-getter-button">
  Get current angle
</button>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, как с placehold.it'ом выглядит. Вроде жить можно, повороты наглядно показываются.

Comment: да, выгладит хорошо, большое спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Все-таки плагин JQueryRotate так может.

Сайт плагина http://jqueryrotate.com/

Поворот:

```
$("#img").rotate(45);
```

Текущий угол

```
$("#img").getRotateAngle();
```

Comment: А можете добавить примеры кода чтобы было ясно чем этот плагин хорош?

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/133290)

Comment: добавил примеры кода